# CSS - "p" tag background does not wrapp

Tags: css, position, width, centering, word-wrap

This is a simple CSS question, however I don't have a clue yet. I have several p tags with a background color, my problem is that the background extends to 100% of the screen in every tag, I just want to wrapp the words, creating the effect as buttoms or blocks. I don't understand why the p background goes to all the width.

Fiddle: [Exact example HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/renzocj/xa3dLLxL/)

```
<div class="process_wrapper_mobile">
  <div class="inter_mobile_process">
    <p>Interview</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inter_mobile_process">
    <p>Data reception</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inter_mobile_process">
    <p>Design</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.process_wrapper_mobile {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background-color: #CCC;
 }

.process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process p {
   text-align: center;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   background-color: #333;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 3% 5%;
}
```

PLease check my fiddle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is block level element, you can add a `span` which is inline inside the p, and add your styling around that. However, you don't really need a `p`, just a `span`

```css
.process_wrapper_mobile {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center; /* Move this here from the p */
}
/* Make the p into a span, it's not a paragraph */
.process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process span{
    padding: 3% 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="process_wrapper_mobile">
    <div class="inter_mobile_process">
        <span>Interview</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inter_mobile_process">
       <span>Data reception</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inter_mobile_process">
        <span>Design</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the time to explain all this. Now is centered and wrapped!

Comment: @RenzoCJ I improved my answer, take a look

Answer (score 5):

The P element is a block element, which extends the whole width by default. If you change the display to  `display: inline-block`, they will only take up the space of the text. Then you need to work on the inline positioning of the buttons.

Comment: This change by itself would cause the text not to be centered anymore.

Comment: It stays centered for me

Answer (score 0):

Update the fiddle check [**this link**](http://jsfiddle.net/xa3dLLxL/1/)

--Added display:inline-block style to 'P' tag 
--Added margin-bottom 10% to .process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process

**Updated Code**

```
   .process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    **margin-bottom: 10%;**
}

.process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 3% 5%;

    **display:inline-block;**

}
```

Comment: The text is not centered anymore

Comment: Thanks for notiftying.updated to display:inline-block. The text is centered now.

Answer (score -1):

Add float:left to  .process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process p

```
.process_wrapper_mobile .inter_mobile_process p{
float:left
}
```